# Need to get all fields along with Aggregate field without using Include Fields in Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

we tried with $project (Aggregation) and Include Fields(Query), but it is including only the Id and Filtered fields. Our expected result is to have all fields in the document along with the embedded document filtered by locale (dynamic key).

Example:

```
categories:[{
_id: 1,
categoryNumber: "12345",
locale: {
                en_US: {
                                name: "Category Name in US"
                },
                fr_FR: {
                                name: "Category Name in French"
                }
}
},
{
_id: 2,
categoryNumber: "6789",
locale: {
                en_GB: {
                                name: "Category Name in UK"
                }
}
}]

Expected Result:

Filter records by locale: en_US(Embedded document key)

[{
_id: 1,
categoryNumber: "12345",
locale: {
                en_US: {
                                name: "Category Name in US"
                }
}
}]
```

Query:

```
AggregationOperation matchOperaion = match(where(Constants.ID).is(clientProdTypeId));

                              AggregationExpression aggregationExpression = (AggregationOperationContext) -> {
                                             Map<String, Object> conditionMap = new HashMap<>();
                                             conditionMap.put("input", "$locale.en_US.name"); 
                                             conditionMap.put("as", Constants.NAME);
                                             conditionMap.put("cond", new BasicDBObject());
                                             return new BasicDBObject("$filter", conditionMap);
                              };

                              AggregationOperation projectionOperation;


                                             projectionOperation = project().and(aggregationExpression).as(Constants.METADATA)
                                                                           .andInclude(Constants.CLIENT_ID, Constants.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,Constants.STATUS);


                              AggregationResults<CategoryDTO> result;

                              try {
                                             result = mongoOperations.aggregate(newAggregation(matchOperaion, projectionOperation),
                                                                           Category.class, CategoryDTO.class);
                              } catch (IllegalArgumentException | DataAccessException e) {
                                             LOGGER.error("Error while fetching client product type", e);

                              }
                              return result.getUniqueMappedResult();
```

Comment: Where is your aggregation query?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `$project` use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). `$project`passes only the specified fields while `$addFields` passes all fields along with the new/calculated/fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below aggregation expression in `3.4` version.

`$objectToArray` to convert the `locale` into key value pairs and `$filter` on locale input  and `$arrayToObject` to convert back to dynamic keys.

```
  AggregationExpression aggregationExpression = (AggregationOperationContext) -> {
     Map<String, Object> conditionMap = new HashMap<>();
     conditionMap.put("input", new BasicDBObject("$objectToArray", "$locale"));
     conditionMap.put("as", "result");
     conditionMap.put("cond", new BasicDBObject("$$result.k", "en_US"));
     return new BasicDBObject("$arrayToObject", new BasicDBObject("$filter", conditionMap));
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({locale.en_US:{$exists : true}});
```

Comment: It will Filter records by locale: en_US(Embedded document key)